# Image does not shows in Drupal content pages

Tags: drupal

I am using Drupal-6, to add image in a content page i used

`<img src="/sites/default/files/mi_image.gif" align="right">`

in body area but it does not show the image however the source code of the browser shows the correct image path and yes there is that correct image.

is there some easy way to add image in drupal content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of the [Image](http://drupal.org/project/image) module and the [Image Assist](http://drupal.org/project/img_assist) module meet 90% of needs.

I personally used and it fairly solved my problem. Hopefully you will like it too. :)